# Android - Buttons next to each other

Tags: android, xml, intellij-idea

I'm having trouble putting buttons next to eachother. I have researched the topic, but nothing seems to have helped.

Here is my XML code: [Link](http://pastebin.com/d6gxDLTU)

Here is how it displays now:
[My screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocagu.png)

If I try to move the enter button down, the clear button goes up and vice versa. I can move the buttons from side to side, but never on the same line as another button

Comment: Wrap buttons into another liner layout with horizontal orientation

Comment: Write some xml kod, don't use drag and drop... It is not quite enough yet!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add two Buttons next to each other? (Buttons with background image, not ImageButtons)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226343/how-to-add-two-buttons-next-to-each-other-buttons-with-background-image-not-i)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right now your two buttons are elements of a vertically oriented `LinearLayout`. All elements appear one above the next, so to get them to display side-by-side, you need to simply enclose them in a horizontal `LinearLayout` container.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout-width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Enter"
           android:id="@+id/enter"
           android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Clear"
           android:id="@+id/clear"
           android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I like this answer. It is simple. However, I suspect you may want to flatten your layout. Read this [article](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html) It explains why nesting is not preferred and offers alternative approaches.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!