# Programmatically setting the layout for buttons (calculator)

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to make a simple calculator that is built dynamically (instead of making the buttons manually using the "drag n' drop" method and then setting their id's in the XML file).

Dynamically as in, placing the buttons automatically on a set of rows using a loop.

### What I've tried:

- I've already tried both RelativeLayout as well as LinearLayout.
- Setting the X and Y values of each button manually `btn[i].setX(250 * i);` but I suspect that this will be problematic when used on a wide variety of devices.

### My *activity_main.xml* code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parentView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/answerSheet"
        android:layout_width="397dp"
        android:layout_height="146dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:background="@layout/rounded_border_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:paddingTop="100dp"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.027" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativelay"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="553dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/answerSheet">

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

### My *MainActivity.java* code:

```
package com.example.calc;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText answer_sheet = findViewById(R.id.answerSheet);
        answer_sheet.setText("test");
        answer_sheet.setFocusable(false); // you won't be able to click and edit.
        answer_sheet.setCursorVisible(false); // this way you won't be able to see "copy, paste, cut" etc.


        RelativeLayout r_layout = findViewById(R.id.relativelay);
        Button btn[] = new Button[10];

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            btn[i] = new Button(this);
            Log.d("test","btn: " + btn[i]);
            r_layout.addView(btn[i]);
            btn[i].setText(Integer.toString(i));
            btn[i].setX(250 * i);
            btn[i].setY(250* i);
        }
    }

}
```

Component Tree:

```
-> ConstraintLayout (id: parentView)

      -> Textview (id: answerSheet)

      -> RelativeLayout (id: relativelay)
```

relativelay is where I want the buttons to be.

[image: screenshot]

While this may seem as a duplicate to other questions on here at first glance (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791317/android-buttons-next-to-each-other), please do keep reading.

Much thanks!

Comment: Refer this link: https://www.androidauthority.com/build-a-calculator-app-721910/

Comment: http://hackpundit.com/android-tutorial-simple-calculator-app/

Comment: @MayurPanchal, both of the links that you have referred to, use the drag 'n drop method. 
I will assume that you have not read my question completely.

Comment: https://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/220-lesson-16-creating-layout-programmatically-layoutparams.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GridLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`

```
<GridLayout 
    ...
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    ...
>
```

While adding a `button` programmatically, it will be appended to children. Don't care about position.